# database record always returns 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, console

I'm new to Rails (Rails 4.0.0) and I'm facing a problem when creating records to the database (sqlite3).
 It always returns 'nil'.

User model (validations)

```
attr_accessor :name, :email

validates :name, presence: { message: 'name field can not be blank'},
                   length: { maximum: 30 }

validates :email, presence: { message: 'email can not be blank'},
                    format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, message: 'User already exist'}
```

Rails console (development environment )

> > user = User.create!(name: "user", email: "user@gmail.com")
>       =><#User id: 4, name: **nil**, email: **nil**, created_at: "2013-07-29 09:27:22", updated_at: "2013-07-29 09:27:22">

When I ask for the user's name and email I get valid data, and not nil.

```
> user.name
=> "user" 
> user.email
=> "user@gmail.com"
```

Then I get **nil** again in the view.

```
 <%= @user.name %>
 <%= @user.email %>
```

Any idea why I get valid data in the console (env=development) and not in the views ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you create `attr_accessor` for name and email which overwrites the setter and getter methods provided by ActiveRecord to set and get database values. Remove this line from your code and it should work again:

```
attr_accessor :name, :email
```

When yo use the stters and getters provided by your attr_accessor's you can set and return the values but they arent saved to the database so they are lost when you overwerite the object or reload it from the database.